# Red Hat subscription-manager list: consumed and installed give different information

Tags: rhel

I am facing a subscription issue with Red Hat. The system was already subscribed to Red Hat. On 2016-12-31 that subscription ended and because it was in auto-attach mode, it "picked" some free subscriptions from Red Hat like the developer tool set.

Today we received a new subscription for Server. We did everything as described. The issue is that when using `subscription-manager list --installed` it is showing old information. When using  `subscription-manager list --consumed` it is showing correct information.

I cleaned all info several times with `subscription-manager clean` Can this be a certificate issue?

Comment: If it thinks it's already entitled under one cert it won't try to use other certs by design. You have to unregister and re-register to try to get it to pick the cert you want. This is more of a customer service question though. Your support allows you to call Red Hat for support.

Comment: @Bratchley That's what I suggested in my answer, would I have to add something to make it more clear ? :)

Comment: @cl-netbox no just didn't see your answer

Answer (score 2):

Cleanup **everything** completely :

```
sudo subscription-manager remove --all
sudo subscription-manager unregister
sudo subscription-manager clean
```

Register the current subscription :

```
sudo subscription-manager register
sudo subscription-manager refresh
sudo subscription-manager attach --auto
```

Go to the [Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/management/subscriptions) and re-check whether everything is correct.

In case that you still experience issues, contact the [Customer Service](https://access.redhat.com/support/contact/customerservice).